# Re-accessing the GUI from terminal/command line in Trisquel / Using TTY properly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, terminal, trisquel

I am looking for a way to re-access the GUI in Trisquel 8 after I enter the fullscreen terminal.  I access the terminal with CTRL+ALT+f3.  After I end up there, I am unsure how to return to the graphic environment.

I have tried `startx` and `xclock` (some suggestions I have found elsewhere in searching for an answer to this question), but to no avail.  These options seem to put me in "no-man's land."  (which is another problem entirely, that I might put forth in another question)

*edit:
I failed to explain the extent of the problem, so a little more description.  Upon rebooting (simple touch of the power button on the laptop), I am shown the GUI login screen.  On this installation of Trisquel, I have created three user accounts.  The problems described above are under what I believe to be the admin account "jais".  When I attempt to login to the "jais" account via this screen, it takes the login info, and then quickly reverts back to the login screen.  So, at the moment, I am unable to access the GUI of the account from which I made all these mistakes. I'm not sure what order to try to tackle this problem.

Comment: Did you try CTRL-ALT-F7 or one of the other Fn keys? Those normally select the different console ports.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with some terms to make the situation more clear to you.

What you describe as "fullscreen terminal" is the virtual terminal (or TTY: Terminal Typewriter). Virtual, because it isn't a physical device you connected via serial to your computer to interface it.

Linux and UNIX usually setup multiple virtual terminals, using getty or similar software. You can switch between them using Ctrl+Alt+Fi where `i` is the number of the TTY you want to switch to.

X11 is the program classically providing you with some GUI interface. You can start it using `startx` when being logged in on one console. It will takeover the console and start your GUI on it. If you don't want to be logged in to start the GUI but rather have a GUI login, you configure a display manager to do that which will the provide you with a -- usually graphical -- login screen. Probably the latter is set up in some way by default.

The takeaway is:

- X11 is already running on a different console than TTY3
- You've switched to TTY3 and need to switch back

Usually X11 is configured to run on TTY1, TTY6 or TTY7. The specifics can be looked up in `/etc/inittab`.

Comment: The default is set up to bring me to a graphical login screen.  I'm looking at my computer with the three accounts, and unsure how to try to tackle the problem.  Should I use ctrl+alt+Fi to access the account "jais"? This seems to be my only option, but when I'm in a virtual terminal, I'm not sure how to proceed.  Does it make a difference which virtual terminal I'm logged into?  I did some poor accounting when trying to figure this out on my own, so I may have logged in as one of the other users through the graphical login interface.  Would this make a difference?  Too many questions?

Comment: @Chaix All VTs (also the one with the graphical interface) run "in parallel" and each is a separate session (ie. you can log in into any of those, even simultaneously). You can always switch between them and then switch back and you should still be logged in. It doesn't matter which VY you are on. Does this answer your question?

Comment: It does, to an extent, answer my question (specifically "Too many questions?") but I haven't solved the problem, which is, I can't access the GUI of the targeted account.

Comment: Then I'm afraid, I don't understand the scenario. From what I understood you a) logged in on the graphical interface with some account A, b) then switched to the TTY3 using Ctrl+Alt+F3 and logged in there with account B (A=B is a possibility). c) Now you should be able to switch back using one of Ctrl+Alt+F1 to Ctrl+Alt+F7 and be right where you where after a).